# emberjs childs nested list

Tags: ember.js

I try to create e nested list into an object "person with childs", but the childs are shared width all parents , this is a link http://jsfiddle.net/Lz7CD/5/.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `dp` array is the same for all your `App.Person` objects, since the object literal that is passed as an argument to extend() defines properties for the prototype of objects that will be instantiated by the class, see http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/ (especially `Extending classes` and `Initialization (and a common mistake!)`)

This can be solved by creating a `dp` array inside the `init` when the `Person` is created, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/AVzeQ/:

```js
App.Person = Em.Object.extend({
    name:null,
    init: function(){
        this._super();
        this.set('dp', []);
    },
    addItem:function(item){
        this.get('dp').push(item);
    }
});
```